# Why is an @ symbol after = symbol in excel formula with EPPLUS?

Tags: c#, .net, excel

This is how the formula appears in excel:

[image]

I want to use Forecast formula in Excel with EPPLUS from c#. The formula in the code is correct but in Excel appears `=@FORECAST(params).`

```
        ExcelRange targetDate = sheet.Cells[listItems + 2, 2];
        ExcelRange values = sheet.Cells[2, 3, listItems+1, 3];
        ExcelRange timeLine = sheet.Cells[2, 2, listItems+1, 2];

        sheet.Cells[8, 4].Formula = "=FORECAST.ETS(" + targetDate + "," + values + "," + timeLine + ",1,1)";
        sheet.Cells[8, 4].Calculate();
```

I want to trim the `@` from the formula in the excel file, like this:

`=FORECAST.ETS(B8,C2:C7,B2:B7,1,1)`

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: I'm running into this issue as well. When it adds the @ symbol, the formula does not work as intended. Would love to see a fix for this.

Comment: I'm running into this issue as well. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

In code you don't need to put the '=' character

Just use:

```
  sheet.Cells[8, 4].Formula = "FORECAST.ETS(" + targetDate + "," + values + "," + timeLine + ",1,1)";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Similar Problem**

I'm having a similar problem with a different formula:
`worksheet.Cells[y, x].Formula = "SUMME(C5:C35)";`

gave me `=@SUMME(C5:C35)` within Excel.

Instead of `=SUMME(C5:C35)`.

---

**Solution**

It seems that EPPLUS has problems with the German formula. The problem disappears when I use:

`worksheet.Cells[y, x].Formula = "SUM(C5:C35)";`

My generated Excel now looks like this: `=SUMME(C5:C35)` (which is what I need)

---

I know it's not the answer to the exact problem mentioned above. But I thought it might help someone. And maybe serves as a hint to the original question.