# Excel adds '@' to formulas with a range

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel-formula

I'm creating an Excel spreadsheet in ASP.NET MVC using OfficeOpenXml.

When I set a formula with a range

```
cell.Formula = "=SUM(FLOOR(I2:I12/2,0.01))";
```

Excel adds `@` before the range

```
=SUM(FLOOR(@I2:I13/2,0.01))
```

Excel is not able to calculate this formula and it shows as #VALUE!

How can I set this formula without getting the `@` symbol?

Comment: excel clearly wants it, so why are you trying to work against excel?

Comment: What is your `Excel Version` ? Older Versions would need to hit `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` and then it would work without `@` as far i know! `MS365` doesn't require `@` implicit intersection operator, quite possibly you are using either `Excel 2013` or `2016`. Note that using `@` implicit intersection operator returns the top most left cell value, i.e. it will be `I2` , can you confirm?

Comment: Use `.Formula2`  instead of `.Formula`

Comment: I'm using Excel 2013. It only works without the @

Comment: As @P.b Sir has commented, here is a link to the explanation from JvdV Sir, which might be helpful as well: **[Read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61138029/8162520)**

Comment: Ah so my guess was correct I believe then, i have faced this similar problem, while using `Excel 2013` and `2016`, if you had `MS365` installed in your PC/Laptop then this issue wont have raised.

Comment: Nice explanation

Comment: MS365 can't calculate the formula with the @ symbol either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have access to the version of Excel you're using (2013), but here's how I understand the problem you're seeing. If you just said `FLOOR(I2:I13/2,0.01)`, the expected behavior is ambiguous:

- Older versions of Excel would treat this as an "implicit intersection", and assume that you mean for it to take the FLOOR of the value of the cell *in the same row as the current cell*, within the range of `I2:I13`.
- Newer versions of Excel would create a ["dynamic array", causing the formula to "spill over"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531) into the cells beneath the current one, to create one FLOOR cell per cell from `I2:I13`.

When Excel added support for dynamic arrays, they changed the formula language to disambiguate the two behaviors:

> Excel's upgraded formula language is almost identical to the old language, except that it uses the @ operator to indicate where implicit intersection could occur, whereas the old language did this silently. As a result, you may notice @'s appear in some formulas when opened in dynamic array Excel. **It's important to note that your formulas will continue to calculate the same way they always have**.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34

If you open an older Excel file in a new version of Excel, you'll see they added an `@` symbol before the range to show that it's using the implicit intersection behavior--the `@` symbol tells new versions of Excel to use the same behavior it would have used in older versions. So I can simulate old-Excel behavior by using `FLOOR(@I2:I13/2,0.01)`:

- if I put this on a row from `2` to `13`, this will give me the FLOOR of the value in column `I` on that row.
- if I put this on any other row, the current row is out of range and I will get `#VALUE!`.

I *suspect* (but cannot test) that saving the file with the `@` in the formula would still leave the file backwards-compatible with older versions, since it's supposed to use the preexisting behavior.

Now, if I use the formula `SUM(FLOOR(@I2:I13/2,0.01))`, it doesn't give me the sum of all of the FLOORs from `I2` to `I3`: it gives me the sum of the floor of the *single cell* on the same row as the current cell. Since there's only one cell, the SUM is the same value as `FLOOR(@I2:I13/2,0.01)` for that cell. Since this mimics the behavior of old versions of Excel, I'm guessing that's why you see the `#VALUE!` result: your cell is in a row outside the range of 2 to 13.

In other words, I think you're seeing the natural result of the formula you're trying to use, and you'd see the same behavior even if you manually entered your original formula into that cell in Excel 2013.

The [`SUMPRODUCT` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e), on the other hand, is meant to perform actions on arrays, in the way I think you intend for this to work. If you use `SUMPRODUCT(FLOOR(I2:I13/2,0.01))`, this should not trigger the implicit intersection, so it won't add the `@` symbol, and you should end up with the sum of all the floors of the cells in the given range. `SUMPRODUCT` is available all the way back to Excel 2007.

Comment: Excel is not able to calculate the formula with @ it shows #VALUE!. I'll update the question.

Comment: @Rachel does it work to use `.Formula2` as recommended in [the link Mayukh posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61138478/120955)?

Comment: .Formula2 doesn't work. 'ExcelRange' does not contain a definition for 'Formula2'...

Comment: @Rachel: What happens if you remove the `=` from your formula string? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23993713/120955 https://stackoverflow.com/a/58423773/120955

Comment: I tried that:) It still gets the '@'

Comment: @Rachel: What if you use SUMPRODUCT instead of SUM?

Comment: Using SUMPRODUCT worked! Thanks @StriplingWarrior!